# c++ compiler error multiple definition of a variable

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn the C++ language (so kindly bear with my noobness).
On following the tutorial in several books I decided to experiment with headers

**I have a file named Untitled2.cpp which contains**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "findaverage.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
cout<<find_average();
}
```

**A header file named findaverage.h which contain**

```
#ifndef FINDAVERAGE_H
#define FINDAVERAGE_H
int find_average();
double first_no;
double second_no;
#endif
```

**and a findaverage.cpp file which contain**

```
#include "findaverage.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int find_average(){
std::cout << "Enter a number"<<endl;
std::cin>>first_no;
std::cout<<"Enter another number"<<endl;
std::cin>>second_no;
return (first_no+second_no)/2;
};
```

**when i compile the program in Code::Blocks, I get the following error**

```
||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj/Debug/Untitled2.o||In function `main':|
/root/Untitled2.cpp|7|multiple definition of `second_no'|
obj/Debug/findaverage.o:/root/findaverage.cpp|5|first defined here|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I am trying to follow the an approach similar to this picture

[image]

Question: how can I successfully resolve the multiple definition issue in my experimental code?

Comment: 1. Not a good idea to use [using namespace std;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice) 2. Please do not post images unless yo have to

Comment: Why is `double first_no;
double second_no;` in a header file

Comment: I guess you are trying to use global variables - this is also a bad idea

Comment: @Ed Heal..I am of the opinion that we can put it in a header? I am looking at the snap from the picture and experiment...I can't say where I am going wrong though.

Comment: Do not use global variables. Put them into the .cpp file and inside the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the header file to

```
#ifndef FINDAVERAGE_H
#define FINDAVERAGE_H
int find_average();
// No - wrong place double first_no;
// No - wrong place double second_no;
#endif
```

as the variables will be included where ever the header file is in a .cpp file

and change the function to this

```
int find_average(){
  double first_no;
  double second_no;

   std::cout << "Enter a number"<<endl;
   std::cin>>first_no;
   std::cout<<"Enter another number"<<endl;
   std::cin>>second_no;
   return (first_no+second_no)/2;
};
```

Should add error checking in case the user does not enter a number - but I leave that to the reader

Comment: Gr8...Seems simplified and on the spot

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you include a header with *definition* of your global variables. Headers should include only *declarations*, not definitions:

```
#ifndef FINDAVERAGE_H
#define FINDAVERAGE_H
int find_average();
extern double first_no;
extern double second_no;
#endif
```

This would fail to build with a different error, however, because you need to provide definitions for your variables in one of your cpp files - for example, in `Untitled2.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "findaverage.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<find_average();
}

double first_no;
double second_no;
```

Note that if you do not need these variables to be global, you could make them local to your function, or local to your cpp file.

Comment: This appears to solve the issue but I am getting another error "undefined reference to first_no" in findaverage.cpp

Comment: @repzero Did you add definitions to your `Untitled2.cpp` as shown above?

Comment: Excellent!!!!.....I think I get the picture now...I'll need to read up some more on extern...I noticed it but never grasp it mentally...

Comment: @repzero The deal with extern is pretty simple. I think you already see what's going on with functions vs prototypes - i.e. the header has the declaration without a body, which makes it a declaration, while the cpp has the header again plus the body, which makes it a definition. Variables don't have "body" either way, so `extern` says "this is a variable with no body", i.e. a promise to have a variable by the same name elsewhere. The same variable declared in cpp file provides the "body", so that he linker can find it.

Comment: ..thanks for  breaking this down to the ground for me..:D